# Add date for 'Last updated' in dashboard

Tags: spotfire

I have a dashboard, with a text area where I want a date reflecting last update.

I have a date column in my data-set which could do it as this has 'last modified dates'

Can I insert a 'label'/dynamic value which returns the max date in that column?

Like this: 
This dashboard was last updated: MAX(last modified column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can do exactly that. I would use a Calculated Value control to do it, since you can have, well, calculations in there :) Label controls are generally for displaying Document Properties, and thus are more "static."

do be careful though! each Calculated Value is its own visualization! that means if you have one, no big deal. if you put like a hundred on one page, though, it's gonna bog down your analyst or web player.

Comment: I find the fact that these can bog down your analyst or web player interesting. Where I work we have reports that are just one big text area (or several) with custom JS, HTML, and CSS as well as a bunch of formatted measures and values, and we haven't had any issues at all! Kudos to Spotfire for handling it well. Could be different across environments I reckon.

Comment: Calculated value was what I was looking for, perfect thanks